# Why did this particular Czech toilet have no paper?

Tags: local-customs, hygiene, czech-republic

A few days ago, I visited a large, modern¹, public toilet at a Czech university which featured no toilet paper in the cabins. This wasn’t simply because the supply was depleted: There was no device for holding toilet rolls (or even remnants of it) nor was there a shelf or even a door handle to hold them. The only place to possibly store toilet paper was on the floor (not that this would have been a good idea). Apart from this, the toilet was a regular European [cistern-type flush toilet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flush_toilet).

You could bring some paper towels from the toilet’s foyer – if you noticed soon enough. And even ignoring this problem, this seems very unpractical as you have to estimate your needs beforehand.

Little surprisingly, my question is: **why?** Since every other toilet I visited in this country did feature toilet paper, I assume that it’s not a general cultural aspect. The only regular of that building I could get hold of could not answer my question either.

---

<sup>¹ Clearly less than ten years old; had electric hand driers amongst others.</sup>

Comment: Concerns about theft and maintenance? I think I have seen this at universities in other countries, although I am not sure I would describe these as “modern”.

Comment: @Relaxed: It also does not explain the existence of paper towels in the toilet’s foyer.

Comment: This doesn't seem particularly odd to me. Paper towels of the kind used to dry your hands are more difficult and less useful to steal than toilet paper rolls.

Comment: I was in the faculty of economics in Prague for a whole week and we always had toilet paper. There were even spare rolls in each stall. It was as soft as sandpaper but that's another story. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO: That was probably the same conference I was attending (but not the same toilet).

Comment: Was it a unisex toilet?

Comment: @GayotFow: No, though I fail to see how this should matter.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, you may have been using a bidet, or even a Japanese style toilet.  When a question is being marked 'unclear' and facing hold status, all details are helpful

Comment: @GayotFow: No, apart from the lack of paper, it was a regular European toilet – I updated the question on this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft oCNS 2015? :D